# Installed seagate sshd(Solid State Hybrid Drive), did a reinstall, now the pc shuts down randomly

Tags: windows, laptop, shutdown

So yesterday i received my new Seagate SSHD(Solid State Hybrid Drive), i installed it in my acer aspire laptop, everything works just fine, but when i came home, restarted the pc, it still worked but started to shut down randomly, sometimes it was 30 min, sometimes it was 120 min, and so on.

I checked eventviewer, nothing! not a single error.
the laptop has been working fine until i did the re install and upgraded my HDD to SSHD.
i also added some extra cooling paste on the CPU, but cleaned it away by now and that doesn't makes the difference. it's not the ram, i already tested that.

I didn't install any software on it yet, also i didn't install any other stuff.

Thanks!

we are talking about a "Seagate Laptop Thin SSHD(Solid State Hybrid Drive) 500GB"

Comment: Can you check your CPU temperature in BIOS? Did you REALLY apply thermal grease on CPU correctly?

Comment: @ashtray: they are stable, it's an older i5 430m with max temp of 55°, also i spilled a bit of paste on the side of the cpu, but i did worse then that in the past so i don't think it's the paste :p

Comment: You should change the sshd tag on this :) sshd is a tag for ssh daemon not solid state drives

Comment: ok did that :p and @ashtray it's a Seagate Laptop Thin SSHD 500GB so it's sshd not ssd

Comment: test with the old hard drive, see if it shuts down.  if so, it's not the new hdd causing it. if it doesn't shut down with the old hard drive, then run  a diagnostic like seagate seatools, on that new seagate drive)

Comment: @barlop ok i'll test that when i'm home

Comment: The issue could be the re-install. Does a repair help?

Comment: @dave rook, nope, repaired it and still shuts down

Comment: SSHD can die... I would send it back as it's new, sounds faulty. However, any patterns as when it shuts down? Any BSOD? What OS (7 or 8). If you turn machine on, leave it idle does it still shut down?

Comment: @dave rook: win7, i just left it idle and it still shuts down

Comment: In case it's a heating issue, can you monitor CPU temp.  http://superuser.com/questions/649538/software-for-alerting-when-cpu-temperature-is-critical#comment816809_649538     Also, consider starting in safe mode to see if the problem persists.

Comment: ok, i'll do that. i'll let you know in a few hours

Comment: @dave rook, the first 30 min it was just 50° then suddenly 120°, there was a plasticlike cover on the processor, removed that, added some new paste and it works fine now

Comment: Wow, we were telling you to check the paste from the beginning, and you didn't :)

Comment: @Ashtray, i wasn't at home so i couldn't check it dude :p

Comment: @Ashtray: and it wasn't the paste... it was the plastic-like cover on the processor that i had to remove because i messed that up when i placed it back, but i couldn't see that because i couldn't remove the heatsink because i didn't wanted to open the whole laptop ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments, I think it's a heating issue.

Can you monitor the CPU temperate (there are many free applications for this, just Google for it) and review any peaks or dips etc. I've responded to a similar post here 
https://superuser.com/questions/649538/software-for-alerting-when-cpu-temperature-is-critical#comment816809_649538 which may suggest how to do this..